# Firebase Push Notification dont persist

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notifications from my backend application. The notifications are received on devices but they don't persist on the firebase to see the analytics. I am using the following code for sending notifications.

```
$fields = [
    'to' => $notification_key,
    'notification' => [
        'title' => $data['title'],
        'body' => $data['body']
    ],
    'data' => [
       'id'=>$data['id'],
    ]
];

$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
```

Then I send the above object through curl request.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You want to see click stats?

Comment: @FelipeMorales not click stats. Stats for notifications like, how many are sent, delivered and read.

Comment: Are web notifications or ios/mobile?

Comment: @FelipeMorales I am sending notifications to ios and android from web application.